# AngularJS filter array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Let say I have an array object

```
[{
    name: 'a',
    number: 1
},
{
    name: 'b',
    number: 2
},
{
    name: 'c',
    number: 3
}]
```

And I just want to get the name:'b' which is array[1] values. How to pass it to the filter?

```
<li ng-repeat="foo in foos | filter:what_to_do_here="b"><li>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="foo in foos | filter:{name:'b'}">{{foo.name}}</li>
```

Comment: suppose there's another object in the list `{name:'abc',number:100}`, then this filter will also select this object because it contains `b` in `name` attributes. is there anyway to alter the comparison behavior from 'contains' to exact match?

Comment: Is there anyway to apply a not filter to this? For example, all objects whose name is not 'b'?

Comment: Yes, prepend the search string with `!`: `<li ng-repeat="foo in foos | filter:{name:'!b'}">{{foo.name}}</li>`. Btw, this filters out those items which **contain** letter "b". For the exact match filtering see the comment link above.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li ng-repeat="foo in foos | filter:'b'">{{foo.name}}</li>
```

might work as well

Comment: Sure, but vzhen wants to filter by `name` explicitly.